# disable input box on check box jquery NO onchange

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

In my project i have a check box that is the basis if the input box is disable. When using the `click` event i achieve it correctly but when i get it in database it does not behave correctly but i get the value i am expecting. For example the value is `0` it will display disable false and the disable is false (default) when value is `1` it will display disable true but the input is not disabled here is the code any suggestion is appreciated

On click event

```
$('#flag').click(function() {
    console.log("sumenu change on click");
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $('#url').prop('disabled', true);
        console.log("check disble true");
    } else {
        $('#url').prop('disabled', false);
        console.log("nocheck disble false");
    }
});
```

Code from ajax success that is getting value and should turn off / turn on input on data load

```
if (data[i].flag == "0") {
    console.log("value is 0 no check disble false");
    $('#flag').prop('checked', false);
    $('#url').prop('disable', false);
} else {
    console.log("value is 1  check disble true");
    $('#flag').prop('checked', true);
    $('#url').prop('disable', true);
}
```

Comment: if ($(this).is(":checked")) {   - is that line correct ie what is the  colon (:) for?

Comment: i think so i got it here - http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2013/02/jquery-test-check-if-checkbox-checked.html

Comment: Can you display where you get the data array? `data[i]`  Also, are you getting the correct messages in the console depending on the input 0/1?

Comment: it should be $('#url').prop('disabled', true); not $('#url').prop('disable', true);

Comment: omg i cant believe i missed that out..must be the eyes ive been working for a long time so i must have missed that @AnoopJoshi

Comment: @AnoopJoshi well spotted!

Comment: of course mate your the best :) you can put that as an answer it was a mistake i wasnt expecting :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a syntax error in your code,

it should be , `$('#url').prop('disabled', true);`

not, `$('#url').prop('disable', true);`